# ios : Json Parsing to a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

```
"SPECIFICATIONS":[
      {
        "NAME": "Brand",
        "CODE": "CML2_MANUFACTURER",
        "VALUE": "Samsung"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Model",
        "CODE": "MODEL",
        "VALUE": "Galaxy Ace 3 S7262"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Color",
        "CODE": "COLOR",
        "VALUE": "Black"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Operating System",
        "CODE": "OPERATING_SYSTEM",
        "VALUE": "Android"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "OS Version",
        "CODE": "OS_VERSION",
        "VALUE": "Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Screen Size",
        "CODE": "SCREEN_SIZE",
        "VALUE": "4 inch"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Screen Type",
        "CODE": "SCREEN_TYPE",
        "VALUE": "TFT - Capacitive Touchscreen"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Display Type",
        "CODE": "DISPLAY_TYPE",
        "VALUE": "Touchscreen"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "SIM Support",
        "CODE": "SIM_SUPPORT",
        "VALUE": "Dual SIM"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "SIM Type",
        "CODE": "SIM_TYPE",
        "VALUE": "Micro SIM"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Data",
        "CODE": "CONNECTIVITY",
        "VALUE": "2G"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Connectivity",
        "CODE": "DATA",
        "VALUE": "WiFi, EDGE, GPRS, Bluetooth, USB"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Storage",
        "CODE": "MEMORY",
        "VALUE": "4GB"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "RAM",
        "CODE": "RAM",
        "VALUE": "512MB"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Processor Type",
        "CODE": "PROCESSOR_TYPE",
        "VALUE": "Dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Camera",
        "CODE": "CAMERA",
        "VALUE": "Back Camera"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Camera Type",
        "CODE": "CAMERA_TYPE",
        "VALUE": {
          "Primary": "2 MP"
        }
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Media Ports",
        "CODE": "MEDIA_PORTS",
        "VALUE": {
          "Card Slot": "microSD, up to 32 GB",
          "USB": "microUSB v2.0"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: Im new to iOS, so wanted to know how do i parse this to a tableview.. Can u help?

Comment: do you want whole code for this?

Comment: the cell title would be the NAME and the value would be the cell description. only the number of rows and cellforrowatindexpath.. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any solution at your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for your question

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewJsonParse;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableArray *arrName;
  NSMutableArray *arrCode;
  NSMutableArray *arrValue;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewJsonParse;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [self getJSONResponse];
  [tableViewJsonParse reloadData];
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
 {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(void)getJSONResponse
 {
    //I don't know your url.So you need to give the URL here and also you need to set GET method for getting response from server.
    //Then follow the usual lines 
    NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *arr = jsonDict[@"SPECIFICATIONS"];
    arrName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrCode = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
    {
        NSString *strName = [arr[i]objectForKey:@"NAME"];
        NSString *strCode = [arr[i]objectForKey:@"CODE"];
        NSString *strValue = [arr[i]objectForKey:@"VALUE"];

        NSLog(@"The strName is - %@",strName);
        NSLog(@"The strCode is - %@", strCode);
        NSLog(@"The strValue is - %@", strValue);

       [arrName addObject:strName];
       [arrCode addObject:strCode];
       [arrValue addObject:strValue];

        NSLog(@"The arrName is - %@",arrName);
        NSLog(@"The arrCode is - %@", arrCode);
        NSLog(@"The arrValue is - %@", arrValue);
    }
 }

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return arrName.count;
 }
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *strCell = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewJsonParse dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = arrName[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = arrValue[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
  }
@end
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you,kindly tick my answer.